# Perform Substring after a specific phrase in a string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to extract a date from hundreds of rows of data in a SQL table.  The field I'm extracting from is a VARCHAR 'comment' field, so users can input anything.

The consistent phrase in these strings is "Date Out".

What I'm trying to do is search from this phrase in the string, and extract the date portion that follows.

So if I have:

```
Hello Date Out yyyy-MM-dd
Hello, who are you Date Out yyyy-MM-dd
Hello how are you doing Date Out yyyy-MM-dd
What do you think you're doing Date Out yyyy-MM-dd
...
```

How would I go about doing this?  I've never had the need to do `CHARINDEX` or `Substring` on phrases like this, so I'm not sure how to approach this.

I've tried a few things but no luck so far, such as:

```
string myString = "Hello how are you doing Date Out yyyy-MM-dd";
string toBeSearched = "date";
string code = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(toBeSearched) + toBeSearched.Length);
```

```
string s = "Hello how are you doing Date Out yyyy-MM-dd";
            //var match = Regex.Match(s, "Date Out=\"(.*?)\"");
            var match = Regex.Match(s, "Date Out");
            string src;
            if (match.Success)
                src = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

The 2nd code block here returns `match.Success = true`, but the string is blank.

Comment: You've tagged 2 different products, which one are you after a solution for?

Comment: Hint: the first solution doesn't work because it's a case-sensitive match - you're looking for "date" whereas the string contains "Date".

Comment: @Stu the one line is commented-out; if I'm understanding you correctly

Comment: What's your code got to do with SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL Server solution would be a simple use of charindex and substring:

```
select Substring(comments, p, 10) ExtractedString
from t
cross apply(values(9 + CharIndex('date Out', comments)))p(p);
```